# Show the given function is of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and its derivative $f'$ exists and is continuous on $(a,b]$ . Suppose $\int_a^b |f'|<\infty$. Show that $TV(f) \leq \int_a^b |f'|$.

When $f$ is continuously differentiable, this property holds trivially, and we could even prove the equality holds. However, in this case, $f'(a)$ does not exist, and I wonder how things would change. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $\{x_i: 0\leq i \leq n\}$ be a partition of $[a,b]$. Then $f(x_1)-f(a+r)=\int_{a+r}^{x_1} f'(t)dt$ for every $r \in (0,x_1-a)$. By continuity  of $f$ and integrability of $f'$ this implies that $f(x_1)-f(a)=\int_a^{x_1} f'(t)dt$.  Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you so much! Using this method, may I conclude that the inequality still holds when $f'$ does not exist at finite points on $[a,b]$? ($f'$ might not be continuous on $(a,b)$ anymore)

Comment: @cxxu96 You are right. As long as $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, $f'$ exists at all but finite number of points and $f'$ is integrable we are in good shape.